# Externally declaring monkey patches for built-in Node classes

Tags: typescript, declaration, typescript-typings, built-in, monkeypatching

I've written an NPM package called [`cached-date`](https://github.com/jtlapp/cached-date) that monkey patches the `Date` class. It caches standard string representations of the date.

Every thing works great, except that I can't get my Typescript projects to recognize the type definitions included with the package:

```
// index.d.ts

declare interface Date {
    toCachedString(): string;
    toCachedDateString(): string;
    toCachedISOString(): string;
    toCachedJSON(): string;
    toCachedTimeString(): string;
    toCachedUTCString(): string;
}
```

The following code yields the compiler error `Property 'toCachedISOString' does not exist on type 'Date'`:

```
// Typescript application

require('cached-date');
const date = new Date();
const isoStr = date.toCachedISOString();
```

The relevant portion of `package.json` is as follows:

```
// package.json

"main": "index.js",
"types": "index.d.ts",
```

Curiously, all is well when I move `index.d.ts` to my project's local declarations folder (`"paths"` in `tsconfig.json`), unchanged, and call it `Date.d.ts`.

Likewise, all is well when I put the following declaration in the app:

```
// application

export interface Date {
    toCachedString(): string;
    toCachedDateString(): string;
    toCachedISOString(): string;
    toCachedJSON(): string;
    toCachedTimeString(): string;
    toCachedUTCString(): string;
}
```

Is there a special way for me to externally merge declarations with built-in types? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. It's a bit embarrassing, actually. Just replace this:

```
require("cached-date");
```

with this:

```
import "cached-date";
```

Now Typescript pulls in the module's declarations and all is well.

Interesting that this suggests a way to load modules without their declarations.